# return error object instead of string in parser server

Tags: javascript, parse-server

Earlier I could return an error object in cloud code/before/after hook using `response.error(111, errObject)` in Parse server version in `2.7.x`

Parser server version `3.x+` requires me to throw Error object or string now. I was wondering how can I return a full error object without stringifying it. Returning object in response is handy because I can say the user which form inputs are missing for example.

Comment: Did you try to throw an object? It should be possible

Comment: @DanielHilgarth it shows my custom error object in logger, but i get response as `internal server error`

Comment: That's normal, when you throw an error in your server code. If you want to have another status code, you should use the same approach as in 2.7

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I don't have any issue with status code. I just want to send the actuall error in the reponse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, Now I have to explicitly call `Parse.Error`

```
const userBeforeSave = (req) => {
  const result = Joi.validate(req.object.toJSON(), userValidator, { allowUnknown: true })
  if (result.error) {
    throw new Parse.Error(101, {msg: 'I cannot allow'})
  }
}
```